# Returning String value of Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: java, string, object

I have the following code

```
TreePath tp = jTree.getSelectionPath();
String path = tp.getPath().toString();
```

This will set path as `Ljava.lang.Object;@33530691`, I understand this is because

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
> the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
> character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
> code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
> to the value of:
>
> getClass().getName() + '@' +Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

But how do you actually get this value as a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getPath() returns an array of String values representing the components in the tree. If you need the String representation of the root, you will do getPath()[0];

Comment: Thought `.getPath` returned `Object` and not `Object[]`, should have payed more attention!!

Answer (score 0):

**String's** `toString()` method is by **defalut overloaded**, so the problem is not here with the String path, but try to see the `TreePath tp.`

I think you need to take a look at `tp`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question. Isn't that already answered in the quote you posted?

`getClass().getName() + '@' +Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` the default implementation of the `toString()` method, but you can override that, if you need a better representation (keep in mind that you need to extend `TreePath` in your case ).

Edit: I think, I now understand:

Since `TreePath.getPath()` returns an object array you get that `java.lang.Object` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

The object that is the component of the tree needs to have its toString() method overridden. You can override it with whatever you what it to return. I presume you are adding a custom object to the tree so you are in control of that object and its toString() method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a comma separated string of the values you can do

String path = new ArrayList(tp.getPath()).toString();

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Object[] treeNodes = tp.getPath();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Object tn : treeNodes) {
    sb.append(File.separatorChar).append(tn.toString());
}
String path = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects (which may all be Strings)

To `toString` these you need to use Arrays.toString()

```
String path = Arrays.toString(tp.getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for output/logging only, I guess `Arrays.asList(tp.getPath()).toString()` could suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The `TreePath` object represent the whole path to go from the root-node to the actual node. If you call `getPath` on it, it returns you an array containing the root-node and the actual selected node, and all nodes in between.

How to get the "correct String" depends on what you actually want to achieve:

- If you want the string representation of the actual selected node, use the [`getLastPathComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getLastPathComponent%28%29) method

  ```
  TreePath tp = jTree.getSelectionPath();
  String path = tp.getLastPathComponent().toString();
  ```
- If you want to have the complete path, you will have to loop over the array

  ```
  TreePath tp = jTree.getSelectionPath();
  StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for( Object node : tp.getPath() ){
    pathBuilder.append( node.toString() );
    //possibly append a separator as well
  }
  String path = pathBuilder.toString();
  ```

  or simply use the [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method on `tp.getPath()` instead of the `toString` method